# Unable to toggle breakpoints

Tags: phpstorm

[image: Tool Menu]

I can debugging, but I am not able to toggle breakpoints. Why?

My xdebug configuration is:

```
[Xdebug]                                                                                              
zend_extension=xdebug.so
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.profiler_enable=0
xdebug.profiler_output_dir="/tmp"
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.remote_mode=req
xdebug.remote_host=localhost
xdebug.idekey=PHPStorm
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to have ***.php** file opened and active to be able to place breakpoints.

Comment: I can debug problemless but where should I 'activate to be able to place breakpoints'?

Comment: "Click the left gutter area at a line where you want to toggle a breakpoint." https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/help/creating-breakpoints.html

Comment: Indeed, I was on the false line, now I can... Thanks